# Building a dynamic row and cell using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html><head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Documents/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Documents/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Documents/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    load();
});

var map1 = { "iDate":"test_value1", "iName":"test_value2" , "iFile":"test_value3" }; 
var map2 = { "iDate":"nexttest_value1", "iName":"nexttest_value2", "iFile":"nexttest_value3" }; 

var list = new Array( map1, map2 );
list[0] = map1;
list[1] = map2;

function load() {
   var beginTD = $( "<td><div class='scroll-pane horizontal-only' style='vertical-align: top'>" );
    var endTD = $( "</div></td>" );

jQuery.each( list, function( index, map ) {
$( "#hpTable > tbody:last" ).append( $( "<tr>" ) );
    jQuery.each( map, function( key, value ) {
        var pTag = $( "<p id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</p>" ); 
            $( "#hpTable td:last" ).append( beginTD, pTag, endTD );
        });
    $( "#hpTable" ).append( $( "</tr>" ) );
    });
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<table id="hpTable" cellpadding="5" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed" class="tablesorter">
<thead><tr>
    <th width="9%">Date</th>
    <th width="9%">Name</th>
    <th>File</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</body
</html>
```

Hello everyone!  Thanks for reviewing my second post. I'm a jquery newbie and looking for figure out why I can't build a row and cell dynamically?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You cannot use `append()` to add element fragments to the DOM (e.g. `<tr>` in one call followed by `</tr>` in another call will not work as expected). You can only append whole elements, so you will have to redesign your strategy. If you give us more information about what you want to achieve, we might be able to help you doing that.

Comment: Hi Frederic, I'm trying to dynamically create a rows looping through a list of maps (string, string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said Frédéric Hamidi, you don't open and close tag in jQuery, you simply add a tag inside another, and use it as simple variable to do some stuff with it.

Then your "each" parsing should look like this :

```
jQuery.each( list, function( index, map ) {
    // you create a tr tag and attached it to your table body
    var trTag = $( "<tr></tr>" ).appendTo($( "#hpTable > tbody"));
    jQuery.each( map, function( key, value ) {
            var tdTag = $('<td/>').appendTo(trTag);
            var divTag = $("<div class='scroll-pane horizontal-only' style='vertical-align: top'/>").appendTo(tdTag);
            var pTag = $( "<p id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</p>" ).appendTo(divTag);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Mordhak, this worked wonderfully! And thanks for responding so quickly...this site rocks and all the people who contribute!  :)

Comment: @sasims you can say 'thanks' by ACCEPTING this answer. Mordhak will gain reputation points. Don't forget to VOTE on answers too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to build the HTML for a table, you'll get better performance by building it up in a simple Javascript string, then append to the DOM once at the end.  Something like this:

```
function load() {
    var html = [];
    var beginTD = "<td><div class='scroll-pane horizontal-only' style='vertical-align: top'>";
    var endTD = "</div></td>";

    jQuery.each( list, function( index, map ) {
        html.push('<tr>');
        jQuery.each( map, function( key, value ) {
            html.push(beginTD, "<p id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</p>", endTD);

        });
        html.push('</tr>');
    });

    $( "#hpTable tbody" ).append(html.join('\n'));
};
```

I edited my original solution to build up an array and join with line breaks.  That is even more efficient than the "+=' concatenation operator, particularly in IE.

Comment: Dan A, thanks for the feedback.  I tried this but couldn't get it to work...I must have missed something?  However, the Mordhak's post worked well.  Thanks again!